# JsonConvert.SerializeObject using an enum doesn't retrieve the EnumMember attribute value correctly

Tags: c#, .net-core, json.net

We are trying to retrieve the value from the EnumMember attribute applied to an Enum. Using the code below we get `"\"South Carolina\""` but we need "South Carolina":

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dto.State, new StringEnumConverter());
```

This the enum:

```
public enum State
{
    [EnumMember(Value = "South Carolina")] 
    South_Carolina
}
```

We tried without the StringEnumConverter as below, and we get the number 0:

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dto.State);
```

Using `.ToString()` gives us "South_Carolina"

Comment: This is correct behavior, cause string containing [`South Carolina` is not a valid json](https://jsonlint.com/?json=South%20Carolina), while string containing  [`"South Carolina"`](https://jsonlint.com/?json=%22South%20Carolina%22) is.

Comment: `SerializeObject` returns JSON, so strings will end up being quoted.

Comment: What you are saying is correct, so tried successfully with JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dto.State, new StringEnumConverter()))  but there is not a better way, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I wrote in the comment this is correct behavior of serializer. You can use reflection to get the `EnumMemberAttribute` value. For example like this:

```
public string? GetEnumMemberAttributeValue<T>(T enumVal) where T: System.Enum
{
    var mi = typeof(T).GetMember(enumVal.ToString()).First();
    var attr = mi.GetCustomAttributes().OfType<EnumMemberAttribute>().FirstOrDefault();
    return attr != null ? attr.Value : null ;
}

Console.WriteLine(GetEnumMemberAttributeValue(State.South_Carolina)); // prints "South Carolina"
```

You can improve this code at least by introducing caching.